# button a href link not linking to page but disappearing instead

Tags: html

I am new to programming and just trying to get a simple button to link to google. However it seems every time I press it, it disappears. Any help would be great.

Below I have put my simple button using Boostrap, I just used the button and added an `href` to link to google with an `i` class of `fa-edit`,

```
<a href="https://www.google.se" class="btn btn-danger">
   <i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i>
            google
</a>
```

Fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36696/)

I'm sure it's a silly mistake, but any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the target attribute it will know to open in a new window I think that is why you are not having any luck making it work in your fiddle.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="https://www.google.se/" 
target="_blank">  <i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> google</a>
```

Comment: Yes it should work you do not have to have the target attribute.